# Python: Printing Pandas dataframe returns numpy.ndarray Attribute error

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm trying to create a pandas dataframe using numpy arrays.
The data, index and column arrays are all numpy 'ndarrays' (2D, 1D and 1D respectively) and all are float64 for the sake of this example.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = np.zeros((100, 15))
index = np.zeros((100, 1))
columns = np.zeros ((15, 1))

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=index, columns=columns)
print(df1)
```

When I print `df1` I get this Attribute error which I cannot resolve:

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'endswith'

The same error is returned when I print `print(df1.to_string())`, but if I print `print(df1.values)`, `print(df1.index)` or `print(df1.columns)`, values as expected are returned.

Am I missing something here?  Admittedly, I'm pretty new to using Pandas, but I would have thought that this simple example would work fine.

Comment: Thanks jezrael and rmharrison - both answers have helped solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

```
>>> index = np.zeros(100)
>>> columns = np.zeros (15)
```

### Detail

You passed a tuple argument to `np.zeros`, which results in an **array of arrays**.

```
>>> np.zeros((15,1))
array([[ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.]])
```

You get an error because i) each element is an array, and ii) `endswith` is not defined for arrays.

Both `index` and `columns` take list-like (includes `array`) attributes. You don't need to worry about whether they're a 'column' or 'row' in a matrix (I presume this is why you were using tuples).

You just want an array...

```
>>> np.zeros(15)
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
    0.,  0.])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ravel.html) for flatten array of arrays for creating `index` and `columns` if source is `np.zeros((100, 15))` and `np.zeros ((15, 1))`:

```
index = np.zeros((100, 1)).ravel()
columns = np.zeros ((15, 1)).ravel()
```

But if need default values of index and columns, simply use [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor - `index` and `columns` will set to `np.arange(n)`, because no indexing information and no column labels:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
print (df1)

     0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   11   12   13   14
0   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
3   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
5   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
...
...
```